# Classify all Rings with every unit having order dividing 24

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm working on the following qual question:

> Suppose that $R$ is a finite ring with 1 such that every unit of $R$ has order
>   dividing 24. Classify all such $R$.

My thoughts are I would like to try to show that there is an $x$ such that $axa = a$ for all $a$ in the ring. So maybe that can tell me the ring is von Neumann regular and then I can use that somehow. The other challenge is that we are only given information on the units, and we don't know much about the nonunits.  Any guidance would be much appreciated

[Source: Jan 2017](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Post_2012_papers/Alg_2012-.pdf)

Comment: If $n$ is the characteristic of $R$ then any prime factor of $n$ must be one of $2, 3, 5, 7, 13$.

Comment: Start by finding the possible characteristics.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yay we have the same idea

Comment: Any cyclic component of $R^\times$ must be $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ where $n=2, 3, 4, 8, 12$.

Comment: From the context it looks like $R$ doesn't need to be commutative.

Comment: Can the characteristic be composite?

Comment: @iYOA yes it can. The characteristic arises from the fact that $\Bbb Z$ is an initial object, i.e. we always have a map $\Bbb Z \to R$, which by first isom induces an injection $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z \to R$, and then $n$ is the characteristic. If $R$ is an integral domain then $\{0\}$ is prime, so the kernel is prime, so $n$ is prime.

Comment: oh oops.  I forgot about Z/n where n is composite

Comment: @Kenny Lau, but if it is an integral domain and sincr our ring is finite we are just looking at finite fields

Comment: @daruma does that contradict anything I'm saying?...

Comment: Multiplicative order or...?!

Comment: $F_2[x]/(x^2)$ has units of multiplicative order $1$ and $2$, and it should put any idea of proving the ring is VNR to rest. Incidentally everything has additive order $2$ if that was meant instead.